# How to list module in opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, pip

I search in google and still no found any that work.

I want to compare between opencv 2.4.13 and opencv 3.1 and opencv 3.2 for python

I know that i can check module list in [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/). But i don't know that list is for only C++ version or same as python version.

ps. my first laptop i download and install manually and second laptop i install by typing `python -m pip install opencv-python` and i get opencv 3.2

So i want to check it and try a difference version to know more about them by myself.

Add more in formation :
I'm not good in english but this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/64036/how-to-access-scene-text-detection-in-opencv-3-in-python/) might help you understand my point. As they say "those functions are just not wrapped into python or java" for opencv 3.0. So instead of asking many simple question about many function because of my curiosity. I think asking this question will help me can learn, compare difference between version by myself. I'm sorry if i can't explain my you to understand